# bootstrap collapse does not animate when opened programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site with a [bootstrap collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse) in it.  I am trying to make it open programatically when the user selects a certain radio button, its working but the collapse does not animate in it just pops in.
The code I'm using is:

```
$("#RadioBtn").on('change', function(){
    $("#RadioCollapse").addClass('in');
})
```

I suspect I may have to do something involving the `collapsing` class, but I try applying that class to the element and it didn't animate either.

Comment: It'd be easier to debug if you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Already debugged it myself and answered my own question, but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found bootstrap has its own built in function `.collapse();` so all I had to do was

```
$("#RadioCollapse").collapse();
```